# Unable to use "USE WAREHOUSE" command in Pyspark-Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to use a warehouse using the following command:- USE WAREHOUSE PROD_DATAMGMT_WH in a SQL cell in databricks but getting the following error. What did I do wrong?

> ParseException:
> [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near ''PROD_DATAMGMT_WH'': extra input ''PROD_DATAMGMT_WH''.(line 1, pos 14)
>
> SQL ==
> USE WAREHOUSE 'PROD_DATAMGMT_WH'
> --------------^^^
> com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SparkDriverExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
> [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near ''PROD_DATAMGMT_WH'': extra input ''PROD_DATAMGMT_WH''.(line 1, pos 14)

I tried putting the whole command into quotes but getting the same error.

Comment: I could find no documentation for a "use warehouse" command. Maybe you meant "use catalog" or "use database" ?